# Putting a variable inside an array index

Tags: c++

I was looking at some examples and ran across something like this:

```
void main(){

    int k[1];
    int b=60;
    cout << k[b]; // what does this line do?

    _getch();
}
```

I debugged it but didnt really understand what was going on.

Comment: undefined behaviour, since it's accessing array index out of bounds

Comment: In addition, it should be `int main()`. And there is no such thing as `_getch` in standard C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << k[b];
```

This line should print the 61st element of array `k`. Since the array of size 1. It will result undefined behavior.

Comment: it just print out zero that was the confusing part. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AreyMSalih printing zero is a valid symptom of UB. As would be any other symptom.

Comment: @Quentin looking back at it i really asked a stupid question. sorry for wasting your time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Undefined behaviour** because you have allocate size of array 1 byte but you are trying to access element out of bound.